# How to show input fields based on mat radio button selection in angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using angular material 9.2.4

im working on the angular material mat radio button with an input field, every payment methods will have their own input field. if clicked 'Cash' will show one input field and hide other's input field.

how to show the input field based on the mat radio button selection?

[image]

**My Code**

````
     <mat-radio-group class="text-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <mat-radio-button class="ft-12" *ngFor="let item of itemsList" value="{{item.name}}" (change)="onItemChange(item)">
            {{item.name}}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
          </mat-radio-button>
        </div>
      </mat-radio-group>
    ```
````

Comment: so credit card and cash voucher will have their own fields? SO like each radio will hide other 3 fields and show its field only?

Comment: @WahabShah yes, you are correct

Comment: just answered it with code snippets and working screenshots. Kindly check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, have a look..

**in your component.ts file**

Lets say this is your itemsList

```
itemsList = [
  {name: 'Cash'},
  {name: 'cheque'},
  {name: 'Credit Card'},
  {name: 'Cash Voucher'},
];

  isVisible = -1; // if you want to show by default some input keep it 0 for first radio, 1 for second and so on. I have kept it -1 so no input is shown by default

onItemChange(item, i) {
   console.log({item, i});
   this.isVisible = i;
}
```

**In your component.html file**

```
<mat-radio-group class="text-left">
     <div class="form-group">
        <mat-radio-button class="ft-12" *ngFor="let item of itemsList; let i = index;" value="{{item.name}}" (change)="onItemChange(item, i)">
              {{item.name}}
       <input type="text" *ngIf="isVisible == i" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
        </mat-radio-button>
     </div>
</mat-radio-group>
```

**Here is your result**

**radio 1**

[image]

**Radio 2**

[image]

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-radio-button-demo?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
<mat-radio-group class="text-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <mat-radio-button class="ft-12" *ngFor="let item of itemsList" value="{{item.name}}" (change)="onItemChange(item)">
        {{item.name}}
       
      </mat-radio-button>
      
    </div>
  </mat-radio-group>
   <input *ngIf="selectedItem.name=='cash'" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
```

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{ 
   selectedItem:  any={} ;  
    eventEditForm: FormGroup;
    itemsList=[];
  public toggleForm:boolean;

  ngOnInit(){
       this.eventEditForm = new FormGroup({          
      'completed': new FormControl()
      });      
    
this.itemsList=[{
  item:'check',
  name:'check'
},
{
  
  item:'cash',
  name:'cash'

}
]
  }
  onItemChange(item:any){
this.selectedItem=item
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i think you misunderstanding my question, each radio button will have their own input field.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to maintain a variable which will always save the value of radio button you click everytime. So, added onClick event. And place a *ngIf in input tags. I'm just modifying your code:

```
<mat-radio-group class="text-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <mat-radio-button class="ft-12" *ngFor="let item of itemsList" value="{{item.name}}" (click)="selectedField={{item.name}}">
        {{item.name}}
        <input *ngIf="selectedField==item.name" type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="0">
      </mat-radio-button>
    </div>
  </mat-radio-group>
```

In your ts add this variable:

```
selectedField: string;
```